# Angular 2/4 Using ngStyle List item

Tags: css, angular

I am learning Angular. I have a ul of names when I click on one of the list items my function clicked(index) is called. All working. How do I style the selected list item so that it has a "different style" to the other list items.

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: `
        <div>
            <ul>
              <li (click)="clicked(i)" *ngFor="let name of names;let i = 
              index">{{name}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     ` ,
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']  
})
 export class AppComponent {
   title = 'app works!';
   names:string[];
   ngOnInit() {
   this.names = ["paul","pauline","paula"];
   console.log
 }
 clicked(index){
   console.log(this.names[index]);
  }  
}
```

I dont have styles defined yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the index of the active item:

```
export class AppComponent {
  activeIndex;

  clicked(index){
    this.activeIndex = index;
  }  
}
```

And then use `ngClass`:

```
<li [ngClass]="{ 'your-css-class' : i === activeIndex }" (click)="clicked(i)" *ngFor="let name of names;let i = index">{{name}}</li>
```

Comment: When you click, we store the index of the clicked item in the `activeIndex` property of the component. Then we use `ngClass` to add a CSS class to the element when `i` (created by `*ngFor`) is equal to `activeIndex`.